# How to solve cannot alloc point_buffer error LAStools?

Tags: qgis-plugins, lidar, lastools

I have just installed LAStools in my QGIS 3.x version. I have already managed to visualize the point cloud through the *lasview* tool. Now, I am having problems trying to classify Ground points from the point cloud to extract DEM information.

Can you please help me fix this error (`cannot alloc point_buffer`) as shown is the image below:

[image: cannot alloc point_buffer]

---

Can you please have a look at the parameters I have as input[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lnou.jpg)

Comment: I believe what matters is there already `cannot alloc point_buffer…`.

Comment: Remove white spaces from the input file path.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.